# Can I write HTML code into a Rmarkdown file and have it output as an HTML file?

Tags: html, r, r-markdown, markdown

I've been using Rmarkdown for a while and I have used HTML commands like 
 of  before but for some reason I cannot get this code to generate in Rmarkdown.

Here is some HTML code I have written and it works fine in the editor of my Rstudio console.

This is my HTML Code

```
<div style="text-align:center;">
  <div style="display:inline-block;">
    <div class="wp-block-image" style="display:inline-block;">
      <center>
        <figure class="aligncenter size-full">
          <a href="https://www.idashboards.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/IT-Service-Desk.png" target="_blank" rel="noopener">
            <img loading="lazy" width="517" height="261" src="https://www.idashboards.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/IT-Service-Desk.png" alt="" class="wp-image-5379">
          </a>
          <br>
          <figcaption>
            <b><u><font size="+2">
              <a href="https://www.idashboards.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/IT-Service-Desk.png">Dashboard Example 1</a>
          </font size>
          </b></u>
          </figcaption>
        </figure>


      </center>
    </div>

    <div class="wp-block-image" style="display:inline-block;">
      <center>
        <figure class="aligncenter size-full">
          <a href="https://www.geckoboard.com/uploads/CEO-dashboard-geckoboard.png " target="_blank " rel="noopener ">
            <img loading="lazy " width="517 " height="261 " src="https://www.geckoboard.com/uploads/CEO-dashboard-geckoboard.png " alt=" " class="wp-image-5379 ">
          </a>
          <br>
          <figcaption>
            <b><u><font size="+2 ">
              <a href="https://www.geckoboard.com/uploads/CEO-dashboard-geckoboard.png ">Dashboard Example 2</a>
          </font size>
          </b></u>
          </figcaption>
        </figure>


      </center>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And here is how it outputs
[image]

Now when I try to copy this code into a Rmarkdown file I get this

RMD Code

```
---
title: "Test Example"
date: "9/8/2021"
output: html_document
---

<div style="text-align:center;">
  <div style="display:inline-block;">
    <div class="wp-block-image" style="display:inline-block;">
      <center>
        <figure class="aligncenter size-full">
          <a href="https://www.idashboards.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/IT-Service-Desk.png" target="_blank" rel="noopener">
            <img loading="lazy" width="517" height="261" src="https://www.idashboards.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/IT-Service-Desk.png" alt="" class="wp-image-5379">
          </a>
          <br>
          <figcaption>
            <b><u><font size="+2">
              <a href="https://www.idashboards.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/IT-Service-Desk.png">Dashboard Example 1</a>
          </font size>
          </b></u>
          </figcaption>
        </figure>
      </center>
    </div>

  <div class="wp-block-image" style="display:inline-block;">
      <center>
        <figure class="aligncenter size-full">
          <a href="https://www.geckoboard.com/uploads/CEO-dashboard-geckoboard.png " target="_blank " rel="noopener ">
            <img loading="lazy " width="517 " height="261 " src="https://www.geckoboard.com/uploads/CEO-dashboard-geckoboard.png " alt=" " class="wp-image-5379 ">
          </a>
          <br>
          <figcaption>
            <b><u><font size="+2 ">
              <a href="https://www.geckoboard.com/uploads/CEO-dashboard-geckoboard.png ">Dashboard Example 2</a>
          </font size>
          </b></u>
          </figcaption>
        </figure>
      </center>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The code doesn't generate and it actually breaks it up into chunks for some reason

[image]

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Markdown doesn't seem to like indentation of embedded html code since it's the same syntax as the code blocks. You can remove the indentation to make it look right or save the html to a different file and call it from a chunk with `htmltools::includeHTML`

Comment: I saved the HTML code a different file and then try to run it in a code chunk but when I put runtime shiny I get connection issues.